# Почему прощаются "пока"?

Tags: этимология

Подумалось: а почему фамильярное прощание звучит как "пока"? Пока — что? Это краткая форма от более развернутого прощания или она появилась сама по себе?

Comment: Может показаться забавным и ненаучным, но интересно, что древнегреческое местоимение времени ποκά (или ποτέ) означало "когда-нибудь", когда-то", "некогда".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю, была когда-то этикетная формула, сводящаяся к смыслу: "всего доброго, пока не встретимся", "пока не увидимся". Устную речь трудно восстановить, формула утеряна, теперь мы можем только гадать, фантазировать. Можно проследить появление слова как этикетного в классике.В середине 19 века оно входит в конструкции, завершающие общение: «Прощайте пока и не сердитесь на длинное письмо...».Гончаров.Встречаются такие формулы: Пока до свидания! Теперь, пока, я с вами прощаюсь. Пока крепко жму руку. Ну, пока всего Вам доброго. Пока всего лучшего. Вот у Огарёва: "Ступай себе пока! А мне своя дорога…"

1934-1940 г.- словарь Ушакова, с пометами «новое, просторечное, фамильярное»: «употребляется при прощании в значении до свидания, вместо пока до свидания или пока будь здоров».То есть смысл таков: "пока будь здоров, а там видно будет".Что-то вроде суеверного "не будем загадывать на дальнее будущее, только на пока". В устной речи появилось чуть раньше в укороченном виде. «Сейчас состав будет. Бывай, пока! Он повесил трубку и вытер рукавом горячее, мокрое лицо».Катаев. «Время, вперед!».

А некоторые учёные считают, что русские по виду слова «привет» и «пока» всего лишь переводы  французских, английских, итальянских выражений.Может, знатоки этих языков попытаются представить такие переводы.